# Group Policy Still applies even after deleting the gpo

Tags: windows, group-policy

Im experimenting on gpo so what i have is i have a server1 (Windows server 2012 ) i create a group policy object HideClock(under user configuration i enable the rule  Remove clock from side of the screen ) ,then i link this policy it works.then i decided to disable the link,then i gpupdate through cmd , and i restarted the computer still the policy applies,last resort was deleting the Group policy object(Hideclock) still nothing was happening

did i miss something ? i need help

Comment: Check if gpresult /h still shows the GPO

Comment: https://sdmsoftware.com/group-policy-blog/group-policy/cleaning-group-policy-when-removing-a-machine-from-the-domain/

Comment: The rules vary from setting to setting, but typically you need to explicitly revert the setting, not just remove it.  In your case, explicitly set the rule to Disabled.

Comment: i tried the gpresult and the disabling it, somehow this is the first time it happened,and also so far this remove clock policy is the only one  that doesn't seem to work , tried it  on 3 vms and they have same problem thank you all, might be just some bug ,all other policy are working

Comment: According to my research, removing the group policy settings re-enables the clock, but doesn't automatically turn it back on.  You'll have to go into "Turn system icons on or off" and turn it back on by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Most group policies (GPOs) are associated with a certain Registry key/value, so when you enable/disable one, the proper key/value for that setting in the Registry will be set. However, some of these keys/values do NOT revert back to their default value even if you set back the GPO to "Not configured". In that case, you have to find the matching key/value for that setting, and set it back manually.

Assuming you're talking about the "Remove Clock from the system notification area" GPO setting, see if this Registry entry exists, and if so, delete it.

```
[HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"HideClock"=dword:00000001/00000000
```

https://www.windows-security.org/bd0d83f723c943c24058775b12451b35/remove-clock-from-the-system-notification-area

It should do the trick.